# What are the shortcuts in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

I am new in windows 8 , i would like to know the core `shortcuts` in the windows 8. which will help me in further use?

i like to work on windows 8, so help me to know more

Thank you .

Comment: (Please don't abuse `\`code\`` for random, unnecessary formatting. Thanks.)

Comment: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/windows-8-keyboard-shortcuts/ and
http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Windows_8.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same shortcuts of windows 7 to windows 8. Some known shortcuts for Windows 8 are following

1. Winkey + s or w or q (for search)
2. Winkey + d for minize all windows including apps
3. Winkey + t (cycle thourgh windows thumnail preview)
4. Winkey + u (open ease of access)
5. Winkey + x (open context menu on start button , only on 8.1)
6. Winkey + h (share content)
7. Winkey + m (minize windows)

Answer (score 0):

in addition to e_sha's list:

Win + c = Charm 
Win + , = preview desktop
Win + . = toggle snap/fullscreen mode
Win + s = search in apps
Win + w = search in settings